# Want to create a copy of the elements on button click

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

I have a registration form

I want to append the contents/elements between the `<fieldset>` tag to the end of row when the user clicks the `+` button.

In fact, the first line you see as a result is re-creating

Thanks for your help

```js
<script>  
  function myFunction() {

  }
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Information Form</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 

 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Registration Form</h2>
    
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_average_gift_size_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--amount-2">
    <div style="width: 17%;float: right;">
     <!-- Begin W_Language Field -->
     <label for="W_Language">LANGUAGE</label>
     <select id="W_Language" class="form-control" name="W_Language">
      <option selected>NONE</option> 
      <option>EN</option> 
      <option>FR</option> 
      <option>GE</option> 
      <option>AR</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End W_Language Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 17%;float: right;">
     <!-- Begin exam Field -->
     <label for="W_exam">EXAM</label>
     <select id="W_exam" class="form-control" name="W_exam">
      <option selected>NONE</option> 
      <option>IELTS</option> 
      <option>TOEFL</option> 
      <option>GRE</option> 
      <option>KET</option> 
      <option>FCE</option> 
      <option>MSRT</option> 
      <option>TOLIMO</option> 
      <option>MCHE</option> 
      <option>CPE</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End W_exam Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 8%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin W_Language Field -->
     <button onclick="myFunction();return false" class="btn1" >+</button>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 12%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin W_Language Field -->
     <label for="W_Speack">speck</label>
     <select id="W_Language" class="form-control" name="W_Language">
      <option selected>4</option> 
      <option>4.5</option> 
      <option>5</option> 
      <option>5.5</option> 
      <option>6</option> 
      <option>6.5</option> 
      <option>7</option> 
      <option>7.5</option> 
      <option>8</option> 
      <option>8.5</option> 
      <option>9</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End W_Language Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 12%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin W_Language Field -->
     <label for="W_Listen">listening</label>
     <select id="W_Language" class="form-control" name="W_Language">
      <option selected>4</option> 
      <option>4.5</option> 
      <option>5</option> 
      <option>5.5</option> 
      <option>6</option> 
      <option>6.5</option> 
      <option>7</option> 
      <option>7.5</option> 
      <option>8</option> 
      <option>8.5</option> 
      <option>9</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End Language Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 12%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin Language Field -->
     <label for="W_Reading">reading</label>
     <select id="Language" class="form-control" name="Language">
      <option selected>4</option> 
      <option>4.5</option> 
      <option>5</option> 
      <option>5.5</option> 
      <option>6</option> 
      <option>6.5</option> 
      <option>7</option> 
      <option>7.5</option> 
      <option>8</option> 
      <option>8.5</option> 
      <option>9</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End Language Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 12%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin W_Writing Field -->
     <label for="W_Writing">writing</label>
     <select id="W_Writing" class="form-control" name="W_Writing">
      <option selected>4</option> 
      <option>4.5</option> 
      <option>5</option> 
      <option>5.5</option> 
      <option>6</option> 
      <option>6.5</option> 
      <option>7</option> 
      <option>7.5</option> 
      <option>8</option> 
      <option>8.5</option> 
      <option>9</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End W_Writing Field -->
    </div>
   </div>
     

   </fieldset>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why did you score a negative?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm guessing it's because your question is hard to understand. I'd add some more info clarifying what the issue is. Also, anyone that did downvote should say why if it hasn't been said already.

Comment: @Matt thank you pal . do you get my point ?

Comment: Basically you want to add another a set of same inputs above the 1st set of inputs on button click. Right?

Comment: @Matt yes I agree with you . but if my question is not clarifying so I'd edit

Comment: @Dev yes exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *[clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)* function for this.

> The clone() method makes a copy of selected elements, including child nodes, text, and attributes.

```js
function myFunction() {
    $(".form-item:last-child").after($(".form-item:last-child").clone(true));
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Information Form</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 

 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Registration Form</h2>
    
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_average_gift_size_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--amount-2">
    <div style="width: 17%;float: right;">
     <!-- Begin W_Language Field -->
     <label for="W_Language">LANGUAGE</label>
     <select id="W_Language" class="form-control" name="W_Language">
      <option selected>NONE</option> 
      <option>EN</option> 
      <option>FR</option> 
      <option>GE</option> 
      <option>AR</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End W_Language Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 17%;float: right;">
     <!-- Begin exam Field -->
     <label for="W_exam">EXAM</label>
     <select id="W_exam" class="form-control" name="W_exam">
      <option selected>NONE</option> 
      <option>IELTS</option> 
      <option>TOEFL</option> 
      <option>GRE</option> 
      <option>KET</option> 
      <option>FCE</option> 
      <option>MSRT</option> 
      <option>TOLIMO</option> 
      <option>MCHE</option> 
      <option>CPE</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End W_exam Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 8%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin W_Language Field -->
     <button class="btn1" onclick="myFunction();return false">+</button>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 12%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin W_Language Field -->
     <label for="W_Speack">speck</label>
     <select id="W_Language" class="form-control" name="W_Language">
      <option selected>4</option> 
      <option>4.5</option> 
      <option>5</option> 
      <option>5.5</option> 
      <option>6</option> 
      <option>6.5</option> 
      <option>7</option> 
      <option>7.5</option> 
      <option>8</option> 
      <option>8.5</option> 
      <option>9</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End W_Language Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 12%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin W_Language Field -->
     <label for="W_Listen">listening</label>
     <select id="W_Language" class="form-control" name="W_Language">
      <option selected>4</option> 
      <option>4.5</option> 
      <option>5</option> 
      <option>5.5</option> 
      <option>6</option> 
      <option>6.5</option> 
      <option>7</option> 
      <option>7.5</option> 
      <option>8</option> 
      <option>8.5</option> 
      <option>9</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End Language Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 12%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin Language Field -->
     <label for="W_Reading">reading</label>
     <select id="Language" class="form-control" name="Language">
      <option selected>4</option> 
      <option>4.5</option> 
      <option>5</option> 
      <option>5.5</option> 
      <option>6</option> 
      <option>6.5</option> 
      <option>7</option> 
      <option>7.5</option> 
      <option>8</option> 
      <option>8.5</option> 
      <option>9</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End Language Field -->
    </div>
    <div style="width: 12%;float: left;">
     <!-- Begin W_Writing Field -->
     <label for="W_Writing">writing</label>
     <select id="W_Writing" class="form-control" name="W_Writing">
      <option selected>4</option> 
      <option>4.5</option> 
      <option>5</option> 
      <option>5.5</option> 
      <option>6</option> 
      <option>6.5</option> 
      <option>7</option> 
      <option>7.5</option> 
      <option>8</option> 
      <option>8.5</option> 
      <option>9</option> 
     </select> 
     <!-- End W_Writing Field -->
    </div>
   </div>
     

   </fieldset>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you pal . 
please vote my question
I got 4 negative ! :(  and I don't know why ?!!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?